# Connect TFT LCD screen with flex band to breadboard

Tags: soldering, lcd, breadboard, tft

I'm asking for clues on how to do this, I didn't found much over the internet as everybody buys their LCD screens with a mounting to the breadboard of as a shield for arduino.

The TFT screen I bought is the following one:

http://www.ronboe.com/vdetail/405.html

As you can see, the connector is a flex band that is supposed to be soldered on a PCB, but there is no some kind of PCB with pin headers? what I want to do is to connect to a breadboard so I can use a raspberry pi to send data to it, I know there is other screens for the raspberry pi, but I need to use this screen to understand how it works and use it on further custom projects.

Any ideas or information to share?

Comment: you have to solder a connector to these ..... http://www.mdfly.com/adapter-breakout-boards/ .......... https://www.adafruit.com/product/1492

Comment: Thanks that just what I needed to know, was looking for them but since I didn't know the name I couldn't find it, please, answer the question to mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `breakout board`.

The link you provided states that the cable requires an FPC 46pin 1mm pitch connector

You will need to solder the connector onto the board, or you could try to find a populated one.

http://www.mdfly.com/adapter-breakout-boards/

[image]